# View latest comments

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, comment-replies

It may be just me and others may have already suggested this but is there a way to view our recent comments in our account profiles? I mean I can see questions asked, questions answered etc.

But there are loads of questions where I add a comment to the question asker and when I leave the site, I either have to remember what the question was to go back and check if anyone has posted anything.

Simply, I think having a place where we can view our latest comments if not all our comments in the control panel/user area would be great!

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. I guess I'll have to favorite this post in order to come back and see the responses, as I'm only posting a comment...

Comment: Please move this question to Meta stackoverflow.

Comment: The recent activity tab covers comments as well as answers and questions.

Comment: @Jonathan - that only updates when something has happened in a question that you asked or answered, but you do not get notified if it was just a comment you made on there.

Comment: @Abs: Actually you do get notified about comments, see the highlighted envelope next to your name.

Comment: @Abs: really?  You must have a different one from mine, then.  If you go to your user name, then select the recent activity tab (rather than the default summary tab), then my one shows me my recent activity - edits, comments, questions asked or answers given, badges earned (but not which question that was for!), etc.  But I guess I'm special and the sites treat you differently :D

Comment: @Jonathan lol :) - I have found the comments place. But it does not show all comments, only the latest ones. I wasn't aware of this, but I still think more is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you view your [`Recent Activity` tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136930?tab=activity#tab-top) you can view comments you left and the questions they go to.

Comment: Ah, yes, I can see some of my comments but not all. In fact it only shows the last 3 comments made and this is on this thread! To pluto with all my other comments!!

Comment: Probably because you have an odd time display. Try clicking **Today**.

Comment: @Abs: that's because technically your current account and the question owner are different accounts. I just flagged for a mod to merge your two accounts.

Comment: @Json - Ah I see, thank you json, that would be great. Just checked my two accounts and I can see everything...awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Now I am able to see all my comments in activity tab's comment section .
[image]